# Create a new dataset column based on the row key

Tags: dataset

I am wondering if there is a straightforward way to add a new column to a dataset if the column needs to be computed from the key values rather than other columns. Here is a simple example.

```
dataset=<|101-><|"Column1"->"a"|>,
          102-><|"Column1"->"b"|>,
          201-><|"Column1"->"c"|>|>//Dataset
```

I want to add *Column2 = f[Key]*, where *Key* is `{101,102,201}` and, say,

```
f[x_]:=FromDigits@Take[IntegerDigits[x], 1]
```

So far it seems I have to go a long way around: extract the key column, apply the function to it, then somehow merge the result with the dataset, which itself needs to be converted to an association and then back. Is there maybe a better way?

P.S. I have a unique row key due to an earlier reshape operation, which I could only achieve using GroupBy, which automatically created a key. It feels to me the functionality with unique row keys is somewhat raw. On one hand, they are supported by some dataset related functions like GroupBy and are shown nicely in the output. On the other hand, joining two dataset on external key from one and a unique key from the other is probably going to be a hassle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some fiddling, I have discovered that `MapIndexed` works for associations and came up with this solution:

```
dataset[MapIndexed[Append[#1, "Column2" -> f@#2[[1, 1]]] &]]
```

or, more cryptically,

```
dataset[MapIndexed[<|#1, "Column2" -> f@#2[[1, 1]]|> &]]
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know it works with associations

Answer (score 7):

I think [Andrei's response](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124865/142) using `MapIndexed` is superior, but I'll offer up `AssociationMap` as an alternative -- partly because it is a legitimate contender and partly to illustrate a work-around for a common `Dataset` problem.

First, here is `AssociationMap` in action:

```
dataset[AssociationMap[#[[1]] -> <| #[[2]], "Column2" -> f[#[[1]]] |> &]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

The result is structurally correct, but unfortunately the `Dataset` type inferencer is presently incapable of determining the resulting type correctly (as of V11).  As a consequence, it visualizes the dataset in a less than useful fashion.

We must invoke the type deducer to fix up the visual rendition.  We do this by adding a terminal `Dataset` operator to the query:

```
dataset[AssociationMap[#[[1]] -> <|#[[2]], "Column2" -> f[#[[1]]]|> &] /* Dataset]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
Association /@ KeyValueMap[# -> <|#2, "Column2" -> f[#]|> &, dataset]
```

or

```
Map[Association] @ KeyValueMap[# -> <|#2, "Column2" -> f[#]|> &] @ dataset
```