# Creating a new Dataset column using a map from a second Dataset

Tags: dataset, associations, map

Say I have two datasets: one is a detailed list of events, and one is a coarse list of events. I want to add a column to the detailed list from the coarse list (for the purposes of sorting).

For example: I have datasetA, a list many events:

```
datasetA = {<|"Id" -> 997, "Event" -> "Flight to Houston"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1003, "Event" -> "Woke Up"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1007, "Event" -> "Ate Breakfast"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1009, "Event" -> "Filed Taxes"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1015, "Event" -> "Flight to Chicago"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1020, "Event" -> "Ate Dinner"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1032, "Event" -> "Flight to Maryland"|>} // Dataset
```

and datasetB, a list of flights (which also appear in datasetA), and a location:

```
datasetB = {<|"Id" -> 997, "Event" -> "Flight to Houston", 
"Location" -> "Houston"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1015, "Event" -> "Flight to Chicago", 
"Location" -> "Chicaco"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1032, "Event" -> "Flight to Maryland", 
"Location" -> "Maryland"|>} // Dataset
```

I want a "Location" column in datasetA from the "Location" column in datasetB using the "Id" column (note that the Flight events have the same Ids in both sets).

If the `"Id"` of event N in `datasetA` is greater than or equal to the `"Id"` of flight event M but less than flight event M+1, I want the value of `"Location"` to be `"Location"` from `datasetB` for flight event M. I want to obtain the modified version of datasetA:

```
datasetC = {<|"Id" -> 997, "Event" -> "Flight to Houston", 
"Location" -> "Houston"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1003, "Event" -> "Woke Up", "Location" -> "Houston"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1007, "Event" -> "Ate Breakfast", 
"Location" -> "Houston"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1009, "Event" -> "Filed Taxes", "Location" -> "Houston"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1015, "Event" -> "Flight to Chicago", 
"Location" -> "Chicaco"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1020, "Event" -> "Ate Dinner", "Location" -> "Chicaco"|>,
<|"Id" -> 1032, "Event" -> "Flight to Maryland", 
"Location" -> "Maryland"|>} // Dataset
```

My apologies for the overlap with existing queries. I think [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124860/create-a-new-dataset-column-based-on-the-row-key) looks helpful; I am still learning mapping functions, especially with datasets.

Comment: You can start by using `JoinAcross` to get the locations from set B into set A at the corresponding event IDs (you'll need a left join rather than an inner join). From there you'll then need to pad out the empty spaces.

Comment: I'm aware the JoinAcross option, but for the filtering and selections I want to do with the resultant dataset, the Location column needs to be filled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a function that finds the last location according to `datasetB`:

```
g[assoc_] := datasetB[Select[#Id <= assoc["Id"]&] /* Last, "Location"]
```

Using this function, you can augment `datasetA` to include location information with:

```
datasetA[All, Association[#, "Location" -> g[#]]&]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, how easy would it be to adapt this to look at the next destination (or two destinations ago)? I am working on my intuition for these sorts of problems. If the answer is "not easy", that is also useful.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another method I hinted at in my earlier comment, but didn't have time for to post yet. It consists of 2 steps: first I use `JoinAcross` to get the known locations across and then I use `FoldList` to update the missing locations:

```
Dataset @ FoldList[
  If[ MissingQ[#2["Location"]],
      Append[#2, "Location" -> #Location],
      #2
  ]&,
  SortBy[#Id &] @ JoinAcross[Normal[datasetA], Normal[datasetB], Key["Id"], "Left"]
]
```